# simple present vs present continuous

Tags: tense, verbs

Are both of these sentences right? If yes, are there any differences in their meaning?

- Jo says what she thinks without worrying about whether she might **be ruffling** anyone's feathers.
- Jo says what she thinks without worrying about whether she might **ruffle** anyone's feathers.

Comment: I have no idea if they are true or not. I do not know Jo nor the speaker. Maybe he is lying about Jo? Although they mean the same thing and both are used to my knowledge, the second one is more accurate.

Comment: @FeliniusRex I meant grammatically correct and when we use each of them. Anyway thanks for your answer.